# Laravel - Undefined variable: request in multiple submit button

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I have two submit buttons for different purposes:

Controller

```
public function store(StoreLeaveRequestRequest $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction(); 
    try {  
    //check which submit was clicked on
    if ($request->has('apply')) {

    $leaverequest                           = new HrLeaveRequest;
    $leaverequest->authorized_days          = $request->authorized_days;
    $leaverequest->available_days           = $request->available_days;
    $leaverequest->no_of_days               = $days;
            if($employeelinemanagerid == $employeehodid )
            {
                $leaverequest->line_manager_notified    = 1;   
                $leaverequest->hod_notified    = 1; 
            }else{
                $leaverequest->line_manager_notified    = 1;
            }  
    $leaverequest->save();       

            $this->getLineManagerUserId();


    } elseif($request->has('draft')) {                       

    $leaverequest                           = new HrLeaveRequest;
    $leaverequest->authorized_days          = $request->authorized_days;
    $leaverequest->available_days           = $request->available_days;
    $leaverequest->no_of_days               = $days;
    $leaverequest->save();                
    }           

    DB::commit();     
        Session::flash('success', 'Leave Request is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('service.leave_requests.index');        
    } 
    catch (Exception $exception) 
    {
        dd($exception->getMessage());
    DB::rollback();
        Session::flash('error', 'Action failed!');
        return redirect()->route('service.leave_requests.index');  
    }        
}
```

view

```
   <form  action="{{route('service.leave_requests.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">             

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="apply" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="submit" name="draft" class="btn btn-warning">Save as Draft</button>
    </div>  

    </form>
```

I used name="apply" for
    ($request->has('apply'))

and name="draft"  for
    ($request->has('draft'))

When I click on any of the submit buttons, I got this error:

> "Undefined variable: request"

I tried to check, I don't know where the error is coming from

Where did I get it wrong?

Kindly assist.

Thanks

Comment: dd($request) on top of method, over  DB::beginTransaction();  to see what it will give

Comment: Is the error coming from `StoreLeaveRequestRequest `?